# Time consuming while Invoking PowerShell Scripts in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I am able to fetch user details from O365 using Powershell cmdlets in C#. The problem is the fetching time. That is too slow.

It takes 2 seconds to each user so it will lead to a time problem if I have the bulk of users.

Here I am just want to print all the user's info like name, group details, licenses. How can I do it more quickly?

Tried one:

```
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline UserDetailsPipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    UserDetailsPipe.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureADUser");
    foreach (PSObject info in UserDetailsPipe.Invoke())
    {
        ArrayList Groups = new ArrayList();   // to hold memberOf
        ArrayList Licenses = new ArrayList(); // to hold of licenses

        string UserPrincipalName = info.Members["UserPrincipalName"].Value.ToString();
        string DisplayName = info.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString();

        //Getting MemberOf
        Pipeline memberPipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        memberPipe.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId '" + UserPrincipalName + "'| Get-AzureADUserMembership");

        //Getting Licenses
        Pipeline licensePipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        licensePipe.Commands.AddScript("$license = Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail -ObjectId '" + UserPrincipalName + "' | select ServicePlans ");
        licensePipe.Commands.AddScript("$license.ServicePlans");


            foreach (var licensenames in licensePipe.Invoke())
            {
                Licenses.Add(licensenames.Members["ServicePlanName"].Value.ToString());
            }

        foreach (var memberOf in memberPipe.Invoke())
        {
            Groups.Add(memberOf.Members["DisplayName"].Value.ToString());
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Graph or Azure AD SDK from C# rather than using Powershell cmdlets for your purpose.  Microsoft Graph API is a generalization of the Azure AD Graph API and normally recommended to be used instead of Azure AD  to interact with the data of millions of users. Please refer to below links to get more details.

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph

For Microsoft Graph Samples refer to GitHub Repository - 
https://github.com/search?q=aspnet+sample+user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories